# Prototype chain messes up while inheriting

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

***This is my code***

```js
const Person = function(firstName, birthYear){
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.birthYear = birthYear;
}

Person.prototype.calcAge = function(){
    console.log(2022 - this.birthYear);
}

const Student = function(firstName, birthYear, course){
    Person.call(this, firstName, birthYear);
    this.course = course;
}

Student.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);

Student.prototype.introduce = function(){
    console.log(`Hi I am ${this.firstName}, and I study ${this.course}`);
}

const vikash = new Student('Vikash', 2005, 'Computer science');

console.dir(Student.prototype.constructor);
```

I'm learning inheritance in JavaScript and all I'm doing is setting up the **Student's prototype** with an object that has it's **proto** as the **Person's prototype**.

I thought the **console.log()** will give me the **Student** constructor as the output.. But, to my surprise, the output I got is the **Person** constructor.. Why is it so?

Comment: Student.prototype got it constructor from Person.prototype. To fix it, set it as `Student.prototype.constructor = Student` just after you set the proto (and where you overwrite the initial value).

Comment: Not sure if you're just doing this for fun, but I would highly suggest learning the concepts of inheritance for the first time in a OOP language, perhaps Java, where there are lots of relevant resources and tutorials. If you're ready to move into OOP in Javascript, I'd suggest learning the new way, [using `class`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/class). Tinkering with prototypes is fine for fun but I would say it's not very representative of the real world of Javascript coding right now

Comment: @Codebling Yes.. I have already learned inheritance using python.. But, JavaScript doesn't have classes like in java or C++, instead it has something called prototypes' and constructors.. Even if I use the new ES6 classes, it's not the class you see in other languages.. It's just a shorter and simpler way to express prototypes and objects in JS.

Comment: Like you said, ES6 does have classes. If you're talking about prototypes, you're talking about how classes are *implementated*. Now that we have ES6 and don't have to rely on object prototypes, tinkering with those directly seems akin to implementing classes in C++ using pointers - a fun exercise but not something you'd do in production. That's just my opinion, take that with a grain of salt!

Comment: @Codebling: another part of the story is that when you learn Javascript and get how prototypes work, a lot of small details start to fit together and you gain much more confidence.

Comment: @WiktorZychla really? I suppose everyone's experience is different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just after you set up a constructor function `Student`, its prototype has the default value of `.constructor` (and it's `Student`) as expected.

However, you overwrite this default value with this specific line

```
Student.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);
```

To verify it, consider your code without this line (and without the prototype chain which you want)

```js
const Person = function(firstName, birthYear){
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.birthYear = birthYear;
}

Person.prototype.calcAge = function(){
    console.log(2022 - this.birthYear);
}

const Student = function(firstName, birthYear, course){
    Person.call(this, firstName, birthYear);
    this.course = course;
}

Student.prototype.introduce = function(){
    console.log(`Hi I am ${this.firstName}, and I study ${this.course}`);
}

const vikash = new Student('Vikash', 2005, 'Computer science');

console.log(Student.prototype.constructor);
```

It seems then that you either have a correct proto chain **or** the correct constructor reference.

This is why it's up to you to manually fix the code to have both

```js
const Person = function(firstName, birthYear){
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.birthYear = birthYear;
}

Person.prototype.calcAge = function(){
    console.log(2022 - this.birthYear);
}

const Student = function(firstName, birthYear, course){
    Person.call(this, firstName, birthYear);
    this.course = course;
}

Student.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);
Student.prototype.constructor = Student;

Student.prototype.introduce = function(){
    console.log(`Hi I am ${this.firstName}, and I study ${this.course}`);
}

const vikash = new Student('Vikash', 2005, 'Computer science');

console.log(Student.prototype.constructor);
```

This way you have both the proto chain and the constructor reference you expect.

Comment: Thanks. Remember to accept the answer if it suits you. Regards.